# How can I spin up multiple node js services inside of a single docker compose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So what I want to do is to have 2 docker container running(MongoDB and Postgres) both of these are working. Now what I want to do is to create 2 services(node.js instances) that will connect from separate containers that will query and exercise their database. Each service should only access a single database.

To show my docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  #mongodb set up
  web:
    image: node
    build: ./mongodb_service
    ports:
    - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
    - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    expose:
    - '27017'

  web_postgres:
    image: node
    build: ./postgres_service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - postgresdb

  #postgres db definition the env vars should be put in a properties file and passed to it somehow
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres
    #the health check confirms that the db is ready to accept connections and not just the container
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      - PGUSER=user
      - PGPASSWORD=1234
      - PGPORT=5432
      - PGDATABASE=customerdirectory
#   Maps port 54320 (localhost) to port 5432 on the container. You can change the ports to fix your needs.
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
```

Currently what is breaking is my `web_postgres` service. When I run `docker-compose up` I notice that the console.log() commands from my `web` service end up in the `web_postgres` Here is what I mean [web_postgres error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfcYX.png). At the top of the image, my `web_postgres_1` service is printing stuff from `web` service.

Is my `docker-compose.yml` set up correctly to have these containers run independently?

If there is something kind of missing piece please lmk will upload. 
Thanks a lot for all your help.

This is the `server.js` file from my `web_postgres` service.

```
const express = require("express");
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const app = express()
// pools will use environment variables
// for connection information
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'user',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'customerdirectory',
  password: '1234',
  port: 5432,
})

pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  pool.end()
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from Node.js app \n");
});

app.listen('3000', () =>{
  console.log("I hate this damn thingy sometimes")
})
```

This is the `web` service `server.js` code that gets printed

```
const express = require("express");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://mongodb:27017", function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;
  db.close()
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from Node.js app \n");
});

app.listen('4000', () =>{
  console.log("I hate this damn thingy sometimes")
})
```

Comment: I suspect the `image:` tags are causing a problem; you're telling Docker Compose that both services are running the same image (with two different Dockerfiles to build it).  Showing the code that prints out the string `web_postgres error` from the wrong container would be helpful, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze uploaded, interesting when I ssh into the container somehow they both share the same filesystem!!! How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `image:` from your `docker-compose.yml` file.  When you specify that both containers have the same `image:`, Docker Compose takes you at face value and uses the same image for both, even if there are separate `build:` instructions.

The documentation for [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image) notes:

> If the image does not exist, Compose attempts to pull it, unless you have also specified [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build), in which case it builds it using the specified options and tags it with the specified tag.

So what happens here is that Compose builds the first service's image, and tags it as `node:latest` (potentially conflicting with a standard Docker Hub image with this same name); and when the second container starts, it sees that image already exists, so it reuses it.

You can demonstrate this with a simple setup.  Create a new empty directory with subdirectories `a` and `b`.  Create `a/Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo Hello from a > hello.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["httpd", "-f"]
```

Similarly create `b/Dockerfile` with a different string.

Now create this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  a:
    # image: image
    build: a
    ports: ['8000:80']
  b:
    # image: image
    build: b
    ports: ['8001:80']
```

You can start this as-is, and `curl http://localhost:8000/hello.txt` and similarly for port 8001 to see the two different responses.  But, if you uncomment the two `image:` lines, they'll both return the same string.  There are also some clues in the Docker Compose output where one path builds both images but the other only builds one, and there's a warning about the named image not existing when you specify the image names.